# Remove symbology title in the legend in AGOL Maps

Tags: arcgis-online, legend

I cannot figure out how to remove the symbology title in the legend in ArcGIS Online. See the attached image. Can anyone please explain how to remove the 'cluster_type_Organization_Type'?

[image: I cannot figure out how to remove the symbology title in the legend in ArcGIS Maps Online. Please see the attached image.]

Answer (score 0):

go to the symbology for each individual one and untick 'adjust width automatically'. No idea why this works!

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't seem to work.